# Flow with For a Selected File Trigger Passes not Info about Item

Tags: document-library, flow, file, approval-process, power-automate

I created what should be a simple Flow: user selects doc in doc library, clicks Flow>FlowName.

It prompts me to add approver emails which I do.  The flow works great, but I cannot get any info about the file itself.

I want to have a link to it in Sharepoint, but for some reason all there is the FileId which Im not sure what to do with. Seems like this should be there.

Any advice most welcome.

Thanks!

[image]

I saw elsewhere that making it For a Selected Item and manually entering the Doc Library name would help, but all it offers me is the ID.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Get File Properties" action, it takes the FileID from the "For Selected File" trigger as the input to get the rest of the metadata.